# Avoid using repetitive dependency while adding aar file as Modular Dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, aar

I have created a module library (i.e aar ) and have uploaded the same in Jcenter. When I add the library as the Gradle dependency it fetches the other dependencies automatically whereas when I add the aar file as module dependency, I have to explicitly add the dependencies to the project Gradle file. Is there any way that I can avoid adding the dependencies that are already added to the library to the main project.

Awaiting reply.

Thanks.